# While loop for reading text file error java

Tags: java

My goal is to read a simple text file, and output it's results. 
For some reason, I get an error for not being able to find the file specified, even though it's in the same folder. I'm a little stumped as to why it's not working.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

class Test
{
     public static void main(String[] args)
          throws IOException          
     {
          int number;
          File inputFile = new File("input.txt");
          Scanner file = new Scanner(inputFile);

          while(file.hasNext()) {
               number = file.nextInt();
               System.out.println(number);
          }   

          System.out.println("End of file detected");
     }
}
```

Comment: You sure its in the same folder.

Comment: Print `System.getProperty("user.dir");` and see if the directory is the one where the file is. If not, use `getAbsolutePath()`

Comment: use System.out.println(File.getAbsolutePath()); to make sure that the File object you are creating is pointing to the location you expect it to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That file needs to be immediate inside your project folder. If its still not working you can use absolute path instead of relative path as alternative.
like e.g `D:\\test.txt`

Comment: Thanks! I put it in my project folder, and it worked.

Comment: I would, but I'm so new here that it won't let me yet because of my status.

Comment: @CarterHunt you can accept the answer by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Which folder are you talking about? If you are executing the app from Eclipse, the textfile must be in the directory where `.project`, `.classpath`, etc. files and folders are.

Comment: I'm using NetBeans. I have the .txt file in same folder as the .class and .java file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to choose a file graphically using `JOptionPane`

```
ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please choose a file");        
JFileChooser input = new JFileChooser();
int a = input.showOpenDialog(null);
String file = "";

if (a == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File selectedFile = input.getSelectedFile();
    file = selectedFile.getPath();
}

//use file input to read in line one at a time
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(file);
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    lines.add(line);
}
```