# Java - importing text document

Tags: java, text

I have a program built and it functions perfectly. I need to change a portion of it to import a text document that only contains 3 values. The text document looks like: 
".35
 .75
 .90" They are each on their own line - stacked on top of each other.

I am attempting to replace these actual doubles in my program with variables that would read these values from a text document. It no longer works when I attempt that. Can anyone please point out what I am doing incorrectly? Here is my code

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class function {
static JFrame frame;


    //Function---showOutcome---------------------------------------------------------------------
    //This function will show the end results without showing all the background data.
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    static void showOutcome(int numFamily, double mean) throws FileNotFoundException{

        //
        //Define some variables and such
        //
        int totClaims = 0;
        double[] rn; //= new double[numFamily];
        int[] claims;  //= new int[numFamily];
        double[] distribution; //=new double[3]
        double[][] randomCValue; //=new double[numFamily][4];
        double[][] claimAmount; //new double[numFamily][4];
        double total = 0;
        double average = 0;


        claims = new int[numFamily]; //array that will hold the number of claims for each family
        distribution = new double[3];
        rn = new double[numFamily];  //this array will hold a random number that is used to calculate the number of claims per family
        randomCValue = new double[numFamily][4]; //this array will hold the random number to generate each claim
        claimAmount = new double[numFamily][4];//this array will hold the claim amounts of each claim

        //
        //Insert some tasks
        //

                //assign a random number to each family
                for(int i=0; i<numFamily;i++){
                rn[i]=(double)(Math.random());}

                //give each family a number of claims based on rn[i]
                String iRec;        // used to hold the input record from the "actual" file 
                Scanner iRecScan;   // scanner to scan for data in iRec

                File dData = new File("actual.txt");
                Scanner dDataScan = new Scanner(dData);
                for(int ii=0;ii<3;ii++){
                        iRec = dDataScan.nextLine();                    
                     iRecScan = new Scanner(iRec);
                    distribution[ii]=dDataScan.nextDouble();
                }

                for(int j=0; j< claims.length; j++){
                    if(rn[j]>distribution[2]){claims[j]=3;}
                    else if(rn[j]>distribution[1]){claims[j]=2;}
                    else if(rn[j]>distribution[0]){claims[j]=1;}
                    else if(rn[j]>=0){claims[j]=0;}
                    totClaims = totClaims+claims[j];}
```

Comment: Would you be able to be more specific about the exception that you are getting?  Are you sure you have the correct file path? `File dData = new File("actual.txt");`

Comment: Ok. You are correct. I'm not sure why I did not notice that before. The sad part is, I double checked to make sure that wasn't the case. The error is with the file location. So I guess I need to add onto this. I saved this text file in my workspace folder in the SRC folder for this project. It was my understanding that that would be correct. Is that true?

Comment: The "path" to your file is incorrect.  The path to your file is simply the location of the file on your computer. An example location in a project would be `src/myFile`.  Depending on your operating system you will have to format the path in a different way and you will have to get the absolute path i.e. `C://MyDocuments//IForgetHowWindowsIsFormatted`.  Try right clicking and copying the path or have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33375625/while-loop-for-reading-text-file-error-java/33376249#33376249) to read the file in using a GUI interface.

Comment: For now, I just saved it to my desktop and mapped it that way. I really do appreciate you taking the time to provide all of that information. It was such a silly error and it was costing me a lot of time.

Comment: no problem! Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

When I run your code, I get a `Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException` which caused by this section of code:

```
    for (int ii = 0; ii < 3; ii++) {
        iRec = dDataScan.nextLine();
        iRecScan = new Scanner(iRec);
        distribution[ii] = dDataScan.nextDouble();
    }
```

The problem is, you read the next line of the file, do some processing with it, then ask the `Scanner` for the `nextDouble`, which, if you've reached the end of the file, won't exist

So instead, you should (probably) be doing something more like...

```
    for (int ii = 0; ii < 3; ii++) {
        distribution[ii] = dDataScan.nextDouble();
    }
```

Comment: Ok so I renamed the file path as mentioned by Micahel Queue and then I replaced the code with what MadProgrammer suggested. It seems to be working. I do appreciate these comments. It saved me a lot of struggle!